# How to change the API base url for my mobile application with backward compatibility?

Tags: node.js, backend, devops

For the sake of this post, let's assume the name of my application is Userbook.

Here are the points that'll explain the situation well:

- Userbook is an android application, available on Playstore
- Userbook relies heavily on it's backend apis
- The backend server is written in Node.js and is hosted on Digital Ocean
- The base URI of the API is https://userbook.com/api/
- Now the product team wants to shift the base URI of the API to https://api.userbook.com/

How can I make the switch from one URI to another, making sure that backward compatibility exists for the older version of the android app. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

one of the possible way to achieve it is creating a new end point's on your backend side and use that endpoint on newer version of your mobile app